# group disappeared from user's group list

Tags: users, groups

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 server edition. I had my user added to `dokku` group 2 days ago:

```
sudo usermod -aG dokku myuser
```

Today I had noticed: that user is no longer in `dokku` group. What could be the reason of disappearing group from user's groups list ?

```
groups
```

says me that `dokku` group still exist. So I can assign group to user again but not sure why user lost participation in the group?

Comment: Are you using LDAP or similar?

Comment: no LDAP there, it's fresh installation of ubuntu 16.04 and I had installed dokku to run web application.

Comment: Maybe run ``journalctl `which usermod gpasswd` `` and see if anything in the logs are useful.

Comment: Did you logout/login after the `usermod`, or start another shell process to check? Modified groups are only applied at login (or process creation).

Comment: Thanks for all comments - I've answered with problem explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After deep investigation of logs I've found the problem:

I've installed dokku plugin for letsencrypt and installation process removed my user from `dokku` group. I was able to replicated this on my other server and here is what happens:

```
> groups myuser
myuser sudo docker dokku

> sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-letsencrypt.git
...
Adding user dokku to group adm
... other plugin installation info

> groups myuser
myuser sudo docker
```

I've shared this info on dokku channel for further investigation.
Hope it will be helpful for others who experienced this problem.